# Maximum call stack exccedwith using KendoUI grid and breeze.js

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, breeze

I'm facing a problem to integrate breeze.js and kenoui grid . I have an observable array in my view model , I fill this array calling ajax operation . when I wire the array to the grid I get an exception "Maximum call stack exceeded" . I read a post that the grid has a problem with the entityacpect inside breeze.js entity.
Is there any hot fix for this problem , or any other suggestion.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard circular reference javascript serialization issue.  It is not a Breeze specific issue.

Circular references are a natural feature of entity models. Consider a Customer.Orders property that returns the customer's orders and each order has a Order.Customer navigation property to get back to its parent customer. This is to be expected and will result in an error like the one you experienced when trying to serialize such a graph unless you manage the serialization explicitly.

You can even get a circular reference problem with a Breeze entity that has no circular navigation paths. The difficulty stems from the fact that every Breeze entity has an inherent circularity by way of its entityAspect property:

This kind of circular reference is NOT an issue for Breeze if you go thru the Breeze *EntityManager.executeQuery* or *EntityManager.saveChanges* methods because Breeze automatically handles the serialization process for you, however if you bypass these methods, which you have presumably done, then you have to manage the serialization yourself.

So you have two approaches.

> 1) Use *EntityManager.executeQuery* to perform your ajax operation. Almost any endpoint can be reached via this method.
>
> 2) Read the following article ( it's about knockout but the issues are the same) and manage your serialization explicitly: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/knockout-circular-references

Comment: Thanks for the reply , if I use breeze with a simple display table (for example bootstrap styled table) I have no problem , this really happen with the grid . And if I use breeze with read only cases then I missed all of it's benifits.

Comment: Please contact Telerik (Kendo's vendor) about this.  We are in discussions with them to create binders for Breeze and they need to hear your voice.

Comment: I've just faced this issue and I'm trying to find a solution to this. Jay, was this solved in any way?